# Find number of visits on each day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has a doctor_id, patient_id, date_of_visit and comments.

```
doctor_id|Patient_id |date_of_visit | comments
------------------------------------------------
1        |     11    |  12-12-2012  | abcdef
2        |     12    |  12-13-2012  | erewrwq
1        |     13    |  12-12-2012  | dsfsdf
3        |     14    |  8-8-2012    | sdfds  
1        |     15    |  12-12-2012  | wereter
```

How can I find the doctors who have made 3 visits on a single day?
For example, the result for the above table should give

```
doctor_id
---------
1
```

as he has 3 visits on 12-12-2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select doctor_id
from your_table
group by doctor_id, date_of_visit
having count(*) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(doctor_id) 
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE doctor_id=1
   and date=12-12-2012
```

Comment: @Sumurai8 Please do not pick on newcomers to [SO], especially if they've done exactly as a 49k user has done a few minutes before.  Why did you not make this comment on juergen's answer?  If this answer is missing some information, why not add an explanation for other visitors?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT doctor_id
  FROM doctor where date_of_visit='12-12-2012'
    group by doctor_id having count(doctor_id)>3;

you can do this here also.. whatever you need

Answer (score -1):

SELECT doctor_id,count(doctor_id) "How many times doctor visited"
  FROM doctor
 WHERE doctor_id=1
   and date_of_visit='12-12-2012' group by doctor_id;

you can any date .. if you dont need how many days visited please tell me i will give you another query

Comment: They want a generic query, not a specific one for the example data given.

Comment: he can use & for this